# Stopping a stored procedures in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

it is possible to stop a stored procedures in MySQL? Put a procedures to feed a database table for load testing with 10 million records , but the insertion is too slow and want to stop the same without having to stop the server ( there are other applications running on it ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to establish a new connection to the database. If you have made the call via PHPMyAdmin procedures will need to use another browser, or close the current completely before trying to enter the database again because the server recognizes that you are still "waiting" to receive the answer to your request.
Run the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` command to see the process. find your Stored procedures that running and use `KILL` command. Example:

```
 SHOW PROCESSLIST; - Will list various processes, see your procedures
    
 KILL 749; - Instead of the 749 set the process ID.
```